# Remap paths used in Windows Movie Maker projects

Tags: windows-7, path, windows-movie-maker

I need to rebuild path structures for old Windows Movie Maker projects under a new Windows 7 install.

The problem is that those projects refer to files of a certain file path that can't be rebuiltd in Windows 7 ("Documents and Settings" is blocked).

Is there a way to batch convert those projects with updated paths?

Some file specs of the WMM file format (for coding a little utility) would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) instead of actual folders, this may allow to overcome the special folder limitations.